# Stopping Error Messages From Appearing

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have wrote a program in vb.net that is using the comm port to deliver data, save on a Access 2010 database, and then transfer that data to an SQL server. This program needs to run 24 hours a day 365 days a year. If the server goes down or the network is unplugged it still needs to run and save data locally.

So this is the problem I have. When I execute the program, and unplug the network cable I obviously get error messages, but I need the error messages to not interrupt the program, I just want a pop up box.

any help would be greatly appriciated. I am not sure what to post for code seeing how there is so much.

Comment: Isn't this what exception handling is for? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315965

Comment: Are you familiar with `Try` `Catch` and `Finally`?

Comment: yes - handle the exception and do something appropriate.  like write a log file.

Comment: I have error handling but it does not over-ride the error messages that Visual Studio is putting out.

Comment: Need more details then as they should prevent the default exception behaviour. You are sure the code that raises an exception is within a try/catch for the *correct* exception type? Are you re-throwing anything? Are you seeing this when debugging? if so have you set CLR exceptions to always throw (crtl+alt+e)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add Try...Catch...Finally Statements to your vb.net code to catch and handle the exceptions.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Will I have to put the statemenet around every problem area?

Comment: where ever you need to capture the exception, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try statement it would be the simplest way.

```
Try

'run what ever code you need here

Catch ex As Exception

'when your network goes down the function that is called to interact with the web will trigger this.
'so you can save your stuff at this part

Finally

'after everything is done you can do what ever you want here.

End Try
```